# What are the top speeds of the different vehicles in PUBG?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

In PlayerUnkown's Battlegrounds there are several unique vehicles that spawn around the map. Sometimes you need to cover a lot of ground very quickly (say to head to a high loot area outside the white circle and back to safety again) and you have a choice of vehicles to take. I would like to know which vehicle would be the best choice for getting where you need to go as fast as possible.

So, **what are the top speeds of all the vehicles in the game? This includes:**

- The UAZ
- The Jeep
- The Dacia
- The Van (VW)
- The Motorbike with sidecar
- The Motorcycle without sidecar
- The Buggy
- The Speedboat (PG-117)
- The BRDM-2
- The Tukshai
- The Mirado
- The Snowmobile
- The Aquarail (Jet Ski)

For this question you needn't take into account hilly terrain, off-roading, or the need to swerve around trees, as it would make the question a bit too opinion based.

Comment: Do you want *all* vehicles? UAZ, Dune Buggy, Dacia, Boat, Motorbike + Car, Motorbike? (Mostly clarifying if you want boat included)

Comment: @n_palum Boat is handy to have too, as it can be useful to know its speed for getting to the Military Island and back. It dosen't seem faster than the Land vehicles though.

Comment: No I don't think the boat is fastest, but otherwise they all have very similar speeds. They can all get to about the same speed, especially with boost.

Comment: Do you want the speed of all vehicles or just want to know which one is the fastest. Because the BOLD question and topic are two different answers

Comment: @KevinTheGreat The hope with this question is to have a good source of information that people can reference for vehicle speeds, since information seems to be scattered all over the place for this game. I can modify the question if you think it will be better less specific.

Comment: Okey I will look around and gather, like you said official wiki doesn't have this intel, nor has there been a developer comment. Most info is based of player testing. I hope that is sufficient

Comment: @KevinTheGreat Okay I have modified the question, Let me know if I missed any vehicles.

Comment: @DrFish I appreciate the update, however this edit invalidates the existing answer. If you think the edit should stand then I will keep an eye on this question and move the accepted answer should a more complete one be provided.

Comment: Well I could have edited one answer, or the whole question. Doing the latter was more effective, I thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some tests and here are the results:

UAZ/Jeeps: 90+ with boost on road, 85-ish most of the time.
Note: The black cloth covering the UAZ does not block bullets.

Dacia: 120+ with boost on road, ~100 most of the time.

Buggy: 90+ on road, 85-ish mostly. Boost does not increase top speed.

Motorcycle(2-Wheels): 150+ top speed on road, easily hits 110 even on rough terrain.

Motorcycle(3-Wheels): 130+ top speed on road

Boats: 90+ with boost

Answer (score 0):

In terms of straight line speed, I think the Mirado might in fact be the fastest with a top speed of 160km/h when using the speed boost